# Classical Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum derivation disagreement

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm currently reading Classical Mechanics: The Theoretical Minimum by Leonard Susskind as I've been wanting to learn both calculus and physics. I've been fine for most of the questions but I got one incorrect yesterday that I could not seem to solve with the answer in hand. The exercise problem was just at the end of a chapter about particle motion. The exercise was about deriving a vector two times, but to show my point I can show the second derivation of one of the components.

My solution, as well as the "Solutions to exercises" PDF, got the same answer after the first derivation:

$v_{x} = -3c\cos^2(t)\sin(t)$

The part of the exercise where a disagreement arose was deriving this velocity to get the acceleration. To do this, I'd use the chain rule and product rule:

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}v_{x} = -3c [\frac{\mathrm{d}u^2}{\mathrm{d}u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}\sin(t) + \cos^2(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\sin(t)]$

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}v_{x} = -3c[2u\sin(t)\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}u + \cos^3(t)]$

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}v_{x} = -3c[-2\cos(t)\sin^2(t) + \cos^3(t)]$

$a_{x} = -3c[\cos^3(t) - 2\cos(t)\sin^2(t)]$

The difference here was that the answer didn't use the product rule. It instead expressed the derivative as follows:

$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}v_{x} = -3c \frac{\mathrm{d}u^2}{\mathrm{d}u}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{\mathrm{d}t}\sin(t)$

$a_{x} = 6c\cos(t)\sin(t)\sin(t) = 6c\cos(t)\sin^2(t)$

To me it seems that in the answer the author has forgotten to apply the product rule, thus producing an incorrect answer. But since I'm not very experienced within the field of more advanced math I couldn't move on without checking this. So I would appreciate it if someone informed me whether my calculations were correct or whether I've done something wrong.

Comment: I think your solution looks right

Comment: Ok, thank you :)

Comment: Tip: Use a backslash before writing trig functions. $\sin$ (```\sin```) versus $sin$. Oh also, that book is amazing. Enjoy it.

Comment: @K.defaoite ok, thank you

Comment: Wolfram Alpha also agrees with your answer, as do I. It seems to me the book's answer uses the first half of the product rule, somehow forgetting to add the second half.

Comment: @K.defaoite it seems like a great book, but I keep finding small errors in the solutions :/ On the other hand, that probably helps the learning in some ways